# Iterator for hierarchical class

Tags: c#, tree, iterator, hierarchy, ienumerator

I have a C# class to define a hierarchy (much more complicated than the example below).  The class has a `Parent` and possibly `Children` of the same class.

I am trying to write an iterator for the top level object that will allow me to access all the contents in a `foreach` loop.

```
class Node
{
    public Node Parent { get; private set; }
    public bool HasParent { get { return (Parent != null); } }
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public bool IsAnimal { get; set; }
    public bool IsCar { get; set; }
    public List<Node> Children { get; private set; }
    public bool HasChildren { get { return (Children != null); } }

}
```

Want to access like this:

```
foreach (Node myNode in TopNode.Contents)
```

It would be nice to have multiple iterators to traverse different types of `Children` like:

```
foreach (Node myNode in TopNode.Animals)
```

or

```
foreach (Node myNode in TopNode.Cars)
```

Comment: Have you considered using different types to represent cars and animals? They could inherit from a common, abstract, base class which would represent the tree structure.

Comment: With the given level of detail a simple `enum NodeType { Animal, Car }` would do just as well as inheritance. Even if you want an `AnimalCar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this method to the `Node` class:

```
public IEnumerable<Node> DescendantsAndSelf()
{
    yield return this;
    if (Children != null) {
        foreach (Node child in Children) {
            foreach (Node node in child.DescendantsAndSelf()) {
                yield return node;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And you don't need different iterators for different types of nodes. Just use `.Where(...)`

```
var allAnimals = myTopNode.DescendantsAndSelf()
    .Where(n => n.IsAnimal);
```

If you take to heart @LasseVågsætherKarlsen's suggestion and derive different nodes types from an abstract base class `Node`, then you can get animals typed as `Animal` like this:

```
IEnumerable<Animal> allAnimals = myTopNode.DescendantsAndSelf()
    .OfType<Animal>();
```

---

You could also declare `Children` as:

```
public List<Node> Children { get; } = new List<Node>();
```

Like this, `Children` would never be null and `HasChildren` would be implemented as:

```
public bool HasChildren => Children.Count > 0;
```

See:

- [Iterators (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/iterators)
- [Sample LINQ Queries](http://www.tutorialsteacher.com/linq/sample-linq-queries) (TutorialsTeacher).

Comment: I decided not to set Children = new List<Node>( ) because it increases RAM usage.  There are approx 2M notes in the hierarchy.

Comment: One other strange thing:  I cannot access the enumerator  myTopNode.DescendantsAndSelf() without using the ().  Is there a way to define this so ()'s are not needed?   Is there any need to have a yield break; here?  It seems to work fine without it.

Comment: It is a method. Therefore the () are required. You could make it a getter-only property instead: `public IEnumerable<Node> DescendantsAndSelf { get { yield return this; ... } }`